# BAM mediator message header/body definition locations

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Where is the message header and body in a stream definition is mentioned in a WSO2 BAM mediator? In the Payload Data? Or can it be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BAM mediator, message body or header must be declared in the Payload Data.